# 3d фотогалерея

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день. Есть [фотогалерея](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=997). Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы картинки с этой галереи не сохранялись в кэш обозревателя? И еще, как сделать счетчик кликов на картинки?

Comment: Классный скрипт, очень просто написан, демонстрирует как можно без jquery создавать эффектные вещи на нативном js. А про кеш недавно было тут http://hashcode.ru/questions/17994/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставить между тегами **head** и **/head**:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Как вариант можно у каждого изображения сделать что-то подобное:

```
{ src: '1ef7ea6559.jpg<?=rand(1,100);?>' },
```

Со счетчиком труднее.

1. Можно сделать, чтобы картинка отдавалась PHP файлом, который предварительно записывал "+1" клик `{ src: 'image.php?img=1ef7ea6559' }`.
2. Наверное, более простой вариант - сделать счетчик на Ajax, тем более что в Jquery он делается элементарно.

Comment: спасибо с кэшем получилось, с счетчиком будем думать